# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable error in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have been having this error and cannot find a way to fix it here is my code
(i am using python 3.7)

```
qustion = pyperclip.paste()

qustion = qustion.replace("×", "*")
qustion = qustion.replace("÷", "/")
list_qustion = qustion.split

op_func = ops[str(list_qustion[1])] # the line where the error occurs

answer = op_func(list_qustion[0], list_qustion[2])  

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qustion.split` is a function not a list of values. What I guess you meant is -

```
list_qustion = qustion.split()
```

or possibly with the delimiter -

```
list_qustion = qustion.split('.')
```